# substituting text into django template tags/variables

Tags: django, templates

I would like to automate writing repetitive django templates. For example, if I want to write a series of

```
<span>Monday</span>
  <span class="field-label">{{ schedule_form.open_time_x.label_tag }}</span>
  <span class="field-label">{{ schedule_form.close_time_x.label_tag }}</span>
```

I want to throw the dates in from a dictionary using keys 1-7, and throw 1-7 to where x is in 'open_time_x'. I don't care if this is done in the template or view (I have a template filter that turns a number into a range), I just want to know how you can substitute template code into the template without it thinking you want to show it on the webpage. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a template file, for example:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <span class="field-label">{{ field.label_tag }}</span>
    <span class="field-item">{{ field }}</span>
</div>
```

Then add a `templatetags` directory in your app, with an empty `__init__.py` file in it, and a new `my_extras.py` or whichever name you prefer:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('my_app/my_template.html')
def my_field(field_var):
    return {'field': field_var}
```

Then you can use a new `my_field` tag in your templates as:

```
{% load my_extras %}
{% my_field my_form.a_field %}
```

More on the subject in [Django docs: Custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: I did all that but now I'm getting 
`TemplateSyntaxError
Invalid block tag: 'my_field', expected 'endblock'`

Comment: Then you've missed a step from Wtower's instructions: probably the `{% load my_extras %}`.